# ZMQ pub/sub subscribe

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, zeromq

I am having trouble figuring out how to subscribe to a particularly "channel" with ZMQ with regard to its pub/sub functionality.

Here is the publisher:

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var pub = zmq.socket('pub');

pub.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');

setInterval(function(){
    pub.send('pub msg');
},500);
```

here is the subscriber:

```
 var sub = zmq.socket('sub');
 sub.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');

 sub.subscribe('');  //herein lies the question

 sub.on('message',function(msg){
        console.log('Received msg:',msg);
 }
```

This works as is, but the problem is that if I change the argument to sub.subscribe to anything but an empty string (''), the subscriber doesn't receive any messages from the publisher.

How do I configure pub/sub with ZMQ correctly?

Comment: You mean even if you do sub.subscribe('pub'), you don't get anything?

Comment: pub and sub arent in the same file or program...

Comment: That's not actually relevant. What i'm saying is since your publisher sends a message starting with the string 'pub', subscribing to 'pub' should yield messages on the subscriber side. All subscribe does is set up a filter on the subscriber side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sub.subscribe('topic')` adds a filter to your subscriber socket so that you only receive messages starting with the string `topic`. You can add multiple filters by calling it more than once. `sub.subscribe('')` removes any existing filter so your subscriber gets all messages sent by the publisher.

In your code using `sub.subscribe('pub')` would yield messages on the subscriber side.

The [pub/sub example](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/examples/pub_sub.js) in the zeromq.node GitHub is a good place to look to understand how subscriptions work.